# When does beam python need `--save_main_session` on dataflow?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

My understanding if that if my `main.py` has `def foo(...): ...` (in the global namespace i.e. `__main__.foo`) and `beam.Map(functools.partial(foo,...))`, it needs `--save_main_session=True` ([doc](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/resources/faq#programming_with_the_sdk_for_python)) to use `--runner DataflowRunner`. But somehow my job still succeeds without setting `--save_main_session=True`. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

It could be that when `beam.Map` is used in the way instead of lamba, the `functools.partial(foo,...)` object is wrapped into a non-global DoFn under the hood.

Try `beam.Map(lamba x: functools.partial(foo,...)(x))` or

```
def partial_foo(x):
  def foo(...):
    ...
  return functools.partial(foo,...)(x)

beam.Map(lambda x: partial_foo(x))
```

and see if it still succeeds on Dataflow.

The bottom line is that if you don't have a NameError that only occurs when running Dataflow (but works locally with DirectRunner), you don't need workaround to pickle things and send to Dataflow.

Comment: “the `functools.partial(foo,...)` object is wrapped into a non-global DoFn under the hood”: even in this case, `foo` is still defined in `__main__` namespace: when dataflow pickle the `non-global DoFn`, it does it in a deep way that include the whole `foo` definition, not just the name?

Comment: There are 2 pickle libraries used by Beam: https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/python/apache_beam/internal/pickler.py#L68. Cloudpickle supports pickling functions interactively defined in __main__: https://github.com/cloudpipe/cloudpickle. I wouldn't suggest coding based on the underlying implementation details as the pickling implementation could change. save_main_session=True is just a last resort when the pickling doesn't work. If it works, you don't need to use it and it's not an issue.